# Unity Pro - Shadow rendering issue

Tags: opengl, unity, lighting, shadows

I am using Unity Pro 4.2.1f4 and I always have this sort of glitch. This is due to the shadows and the bias. Even with a low bias this is happening.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've found a thread that talks about that but I don't find it anymore.
What is the technical reason about that issue ?
Where does it come from ? Is there a way to avoid/minimize that problem ?

Thanks a lot.